# Show GEO IP information in Firefox when using tor

Tags: ip, firefox, tor, geolocation

I've configured Firefox to use TOR (SOCKS proxy via localhost). Everything works great, but I would like to see at any time which IP in which country I'm using.

is there a Firefox Addon, which displays my current IP together with the country code (or flag)?

I could only find addons which display the current IP, but IP alone does not tell me where the IP is GEO located.

Answer (score 1):

I use the *IP Address and Domain Information* addon. It offers you a small icon in the toolbar, and offers all sorts of information about domain/ip/dns. When you click on it, the *My IP* tab shows your IP and location and some other information like the owning provider, whether it's on any spam/blacklists and even a map of the approximate location.

Works great with proxies as well (and indeed shows the exit-IP, not your own).

This is the one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ip-address-and-domain-info/?src=search

Comment: thanks, but this addon looks much too overcomplicated. I was hoping for a small flag somewhere in the corner of my window

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Live IP Address Addon Which lets you update the ip as well and copy Your current ip address

You can get it [HERE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-ip-address/)

Comment: This addon would have been a perfect solution, if only it showed the IP "live" as it's name suggests. But unfortunately, it does not register IP Address change and only allows to set ridiculously long intervals between refresh (minimum is 17 minutes).